# Find the limit as x approaches 0 from the right of $x^a\ln x$

Tags: calculus, limits

where $a$ is a positive constant.

I've gone ahead and assumed it requires l'hopitals rule - meaning product rule. 
So I've got $ax^{a-1}\ln x+\dfrac{x^a}{x}$. Where to from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to use the L'Hospital's rule. Let us put $y = 1/x$ so that when $x
\to 0^{+}$ then $y \to \infty$. We then see that $x^{a}\log x = -\dfrac{\log y}{y^{a}} = -f(y)$. We will now try to find $\lim_{y \to \infty}f(y)$. Since $y \to \infty$ we can take $y > 1$. By any definition of $\log$ is it easy to show that $0 < \log y \leq y - 1$. Let us take a number $b$ with $0 < b < a$. Then $\log y^{b} < y^{b} - 1$ and hence $b\log y < y^{b} - 1$. It follows that we have $$0 < \log y \leq \frac{y^{b} - 1}{b}$$ and hence $$0 < f(y) = \frac{\log y}{y^{a}} \leq \frac{1}{by^{a - b}} - \frac{1}{by^{a}}$$ Now taking limits as $y \to \infty$ and noting that both $a$ and $a - b$ are positive we get $\lim_{y \to \infty}f(y) = 0$. Hence the original limit is also $0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If you want to use L'hospital rule, you should write it as: $f(x)=\dfrac{\ln x}{x^{-a}}$.
Apply the rule we have: $f(x) \to \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{x}}{-ax^{-a-1}} = -\dfrac{x^a}{a} \to 0$.